# What ExtJS 3 pitfalls should I avoid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am about to write a relative small data entry application using ExtJS 3+ for the front end, what pitfalls should I avoid when using ExtJS 3+?

- One pitfall that comes to mind is not truly understanding
  JavaScript (e.g.closures)
- Trying to use MVC pattern on the client side.

Comment: community wiki seems appropriate here.

Comment: Not understanding JS would be a pitfall with any JS-based framework I would think...

Answer (score 2):

Choose your design *deliberately*: keep a clear separation between the Ext JS UI (front-end) and the web service (back-end). **Do not** use a back-end scripting language to render your JavaScript - write Ext JS code purely in *.js files and communicate to RESTful JSON web services as needed.

Comment: This is golden. I am having a very rough time working with a legacy codebase right now, having to move from ColdExt to raw Ext, and then from Ext 3 to Ext 4. Rough stuff, which would have been much easier to work through had the JS all been created on a "level playing field", if you will, and without the use of server-side preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye out for executing things in your object (JSON) definition.

```
function MyPanel() {
}

function createParam() {
  return {param: 'value'};
}

Ext.extend(MyPanel, ext.Panel, {
  someParam = createParam();
});
```

In the above example the stuff inside `Ext.Extend` will get executed once when Javascript is loaded. This means that all instances of MyPanel will share the same instance of someParam. In this scenario such initialization needs to go in the constructor:

```
function MyPanel() {
  this.someParam = createParam();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proper namespaces so you don't pollute the global namespace, Ext.ns() is your friend here:

```
Ext.ns("AlexanderN.Application");

AlexanderN.Application.MainWindow = Ext.extend(Ext.Window,{
  ...
});
```

etc.